# How do I send a PUT request with JSON body with cURL?

Tags: php, curl, put

I have this code to send a PUT request:

```
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, true);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_BODY, json_encode($result));

curl_exec($curl);
```

But that doesn't work, because `CURLOPT_BODY` does not exist. But, how do I add a body to my `PUT` request? I tried `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, but that transforms my call into a `POST` (and I really do need a `PUT`).

Comment: You could also try `CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT"` along with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` instead of `CURLOPT_PUT`. For `PUT`, you will need an `CURLOPT_INFILE`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cURL cannot inherently do a `PUT` request.

You need to do the following:

```php
$curl = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($result));
curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$response = curl_exec($curl);
```

Comment: I did get it working with `CURLOPT_INFILE` and `CURLOPT_INFILESIZE`, but it added some extra code to create a stream from my string. Your solution is shorter.

Comment: don't use CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST for PUT. use CURLOPT_UPLOAD

Comment: @hanshenrik Could you elaborate so I can edit my answer accordingly? Thanks.

Comment: @JustCarty replace ```curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "PUT");``` with ```curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_UPLOAD, true);```